# How to subtract with OOP PHP?

Tags: php, oop, math, subtraction

I am using oop php and I don't know how to subtract some equations that I have or how to do some arithmetic's.

For example:

```
class a {
public $account = "£1.00";
public $remove = ""
}

$p = new a;
$p->account = "£20.00";
$p->remove = "£5.00";

echo $p->account;
echo $p->remove;
```

So, as you can see in the example above is there a way I can subtract, add, multiple and divide. Also, is there a way to do percentages.

If someone can please help me, it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: You're trying to do math with text strings.  If you want to do math, use numbers.

Comment: If we're talking `OOP`, I'd suggest adding class methods for `substract` and not accessing the members directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove the Pound sign and it will be even better if you don't use strings but float values.

```
$addition_result = $p->account + $p->remove; //add
$subtraction_result = $p->account - $p->remove; //subtraction
$division_result = $p->account / $p->remove; //division
```

You can go ahead and echo those results.

Answer (score 0):

What? You can use it just like anything else.

```
class a {
public $account = 5.00;
public $remove = 4.00
public $total = 0;
}

$p = new a;
$p->total = $p->account - $p->remove;

echo $p->total;
```